# PHP intval function rounds down an integer number

Tags: php, casting, int, rounding

This is the most idiot behavior I have seen in PHP.

```
$num = 4400 / 1.1;
echo doubleval($num); // prints 4000
echo intval($num); // prints 3999
```

Why that's happening and how to solve it?

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37554 & https://eval.in/478237

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect: an in-depth comparison of the inner workings of intval and the implicit cast to string including the IEEE 754 representation of a float/double and the rules of the C standard libs when printing a double, why the php devs didn't care about it or just how (and when) to handle such things (in general or for this particular case)?

Comment: btw: since you have some points for the javascript tag: https://jsfiddle.net/9e4ssjmj/  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Numbers like 0.1 and 0.7 don't work well with the binary representation.
Read the 'Warning' section  [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

If you need to divide by 1.1, I suggest you do:

```
$num = (4400 * 10) / 11;
```

or

```
$num = (4400 * 10.0) / 11;
```

since 11 can be exactly represented as a binary number.

intval() will truncate the inexact result to nearest **below**
doubleval() will be rounded to nearest.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is inherited from `C` language.

There will be a small difference while comparing floating values,

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), ans [this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/5836/What-Every-Computer-Scientist-Should-Know-About-Floating-Point-Arithmetic)

try this,

```
$tot = 0;
$ans = (float)101;
for($i=1; $i<= 10; $i++){
    $tot = $tot + 10.1;
}

if (abs(($tot-$ans)/$tot) < 0.00001) {
    echo '<br />Both are equal ';
}
else{
    echo '<br />Both are not equal ';
}
```

With [`abs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) output is

```
Both are equal
```

Without [`abs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) output is

```
Both are not equal
```

For above remove [`abs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php), it will enter `else` even though the values are same(there will be a small difference in decimals)

So use [`abs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) to solve this issue